# Jest Mocking inner function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am writing Jest test and in involves mocking Google's Firebase classes

1. this is the function that I want to mock `sendNotification`

   ```
   async function sendNotification ({userId, title, message, type}) {
       // create notification
       const isRead = false;
       const newNotification = await createNotification({userId, title, message, type, isRead})
       // retrieve user FCM token
       const userFCMTokenList = await userFCMTokenService.fetchUserFCMToken(userId);
       // send notification to the user
       if(userFCMTokenList.length > 0) {
           const sendNotificationData = {
               data: {
                   id: newNotification.id,
                   title: newNotification.title,
                   message: newNotification.message,
                   type: newNotification.type,
                   created_at: JSON.stringify(newNotification.created_at)
               },
               tokens: userFCMTokenList
           };

               admin.messaging().sendMulticast(sendNotificationData).then((response) => {
               console.log(response.successCount + ' messages were sent successfully');
           }).catch(function (e) {
               console.error('Failed to send notification to ' + userId, e.toString());
               Sentry.captureException(e);
           });
       } else {
           console.log('Unable to find user FCM tokens to send notification to ' + userId);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Here is the Jest test:

   ```
   it('should sendNotification', async function(){
           const tokents = [
               faker.random.alphaNumeric(12)
           ];
           db.moxyNotification.addNotification.mockReturnValue(
               notificationData
           );

           const result = NotificationService.sendNotification(
               {
                   usedId: 'notificationId',
                   title: 'notification title',
                   message: 'notification message',
                   type: 'global'
               });

           jest.spyOn(userFCMTokenService, 'fetchUserFCMToken').mockImplementationOnce(jest.fn().
           mockReturnValue(
               [
               {'FMTtoekn': '112233'}
           ]));

           jest.spyOn(admin, 'messaging').mockImplementationOnce(
               sendMulticast = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))
           );

       });
   ```

How do I mock `admin.messaging().sendMulticast()` function from the firebase package?

Comment: How is admin created/imported ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top level you need to mock admin module (Assuming it's a module)

```
//extract the inner mock
const mockSendMultiCast = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    //Do your thing like Promise.resolve()
})

jest.mock('admin', () => ({
    messaging: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      sendMulticast: mockSendMultiCast 
}))}));
// now you can check because it is a mock
expect(mockSendMultiCast).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Prefer `jest.fn()` over `() => {}` when you want to later `spyOn` or `expect` on the mocked method

Just to further push the nail in - if you want to mock differently for tests - at the beginning of the `it` or `test` scope:

```
mockSendMultiCast.mockImplementationOnce( jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  But then when I tried to spyOn  the inner sendMulticast method.. it doesn't work.  It would say **Error: Property messaging does not have access type sendMulticast**


```
jest.spyOn(admin, 'messaging', 'sendMulticast').mockImplementationOnce(
            jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} }))
        );
```

Is this how you do it?

Comment: You can't spy levels deep. You need to mock, updating answer

Comment: Thanks dude, it worked!
Don't know how I would ever figure this out.  This is not mentioned in their official documentation at all...