# How to write unit test case to mock neo4j calls using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, jestjs, nestjs

Can you please help me to mock the driver.session and session.run in executeQuery function?

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import neo4j, { Driver } from 'neo4j-driver';
import { IDBService } from './db-service.interface';
@Injectable()
export class DBService implements IDBService {
  private driver: Driver;
  constructor() { 
    const uri = 'graph_uri';
    const user = 'graph_user';
    const password = 'graph_password';
    this.driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password), {
      disableLosslessIntegers: true,
      encrypted: true
    });
    }
  public async executeQuery(statement: any, params: {}) {
    const session = this.driver.session();
    try {
      let result = await session.run(statement, params);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    } finally {
      await session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to mock the neo4j calls but its not mocking properly.

```
describe('Tests for executeQuery() function', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(300000);
    it("Return success response for executeQuery()", async () => {
        jest.spyOn(session, 'run').mockResolvedValue(mockData)
        let queryString: string = `MATCH (n:Users{user_id:1}) RETURN n.user_id`
        let result = await DBService.executeQuery(queryString, {});
        expect(typeof result).toBe('object');
    })
});
let mockData: any = {
  "records": [ {  "_fields": [ {  "properties": {"user_id": 1 } }]} ],
  "summary": { "query": {"text": "MATCH (n:Users{user_id:1}) RETURN n","parameters": {} }}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest Mocking inner function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75790298/jest-mocking-inner-function)